# Get changes to file after git merge

Tags: git

I'm trying to understand the changes to hapi/index.d.ts after this merge: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/11739

With the following:

```
git checkout 80060c9
git show 80060c9 hapi/index.d.ts
```

This `git show` output shows 26 insertions and 21 deletions.  However the (very long) commit message does not mention hapi explicitly, only an unrelated [hapi-decorators merged pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/11668/commits/b4b2090670c412f770a21ccef0d333762f11887f).  I'm wondering what these changes to hapi/index.d.ts are, and wanted to confirm whether they originate from commit 80060c9 as opposed to originally coming from a different commit with a more descriptive commit message.

Comment: I work on a project that might help you. It provides the mixture of diff and blame at the same time.https://github.com/eantoranz/difflame Hope it can help you understand what's going on.